# I'm a newbie and want to learn web3, where to start?

Tags: web3js, blockchain

i have a desire to learn coding, programming and web3 website building. i've been searching for a while and got to many resources but i don't know where to start. if someone can guide me to the right start for me to be able to get on the journey and keep going. i appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Narrow down exactly what you want to do and focus on that.
If wanting to build websites  you can get by on node js, react and subgraph. You can do front end for web3 while barely understanding solidity.

If you reject that idea and feel you would really like to understand smart contracts then build a project that incorporates one.

Pick the field, type of protocol, styles of contracts.
Do you want to work in defi, or gamefi, do you like nft's etc. narrow it down and the path will become clearer.

A great way to learn is just by staying interested, and repeatedly building. So put the effort into what you care about and what inspires you to stay focused.
Build small projects that you can finish.

Utilise documentation and experimentation as much as possible, with as little copying as you can bare.
But it's more important to be inspired to keep going, so try things out, and then focus on the narrowest possible area that inspires you. Can expand later.

There are a lot of brilliant people in the space and a jack of all trades can find it hard to add something to a room, but if you can specialize in even one area that no one else in that room does, you'll have a reason to be there.

You said you have a bunch of resources, so will only add a couple.

Patrick has a ton of example projects, and will even go to the effort of having some fully audited.
You can find him asking and answering questions on this stack.
https://www.youtube.com/@PatrickAlphaC

If you would like to understand more about interacting with smart contracts, their construction or the math behind them, and to have it explained in a slow and clear way, Smart Contract Programmer has a wonderful channel.
https://www.youtube.com/@smartcontractprogrammer

Good luck on your journey.

Answer (score 0):

easy,

firstly open remix site and start copying solidity contract into it, deploy and test. working from backwards how this works. Use this, very basic contract >>> https://wizard.openzeppelin.com/

secondly, once you start to understand constructor, functions, import, mapping and etc from the very basic contract, then try play around by editing and adding more.

thirdly, start watching videos of what you want to achieve and follow them.

finally, go rogue. testing, innovate, and come back to this forum to debug.